# How to make an image view and a label adaptive to each other in swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, imageview, label

I have a UI View, which consists of image view and a label. UI view has constraints set up to the superview. These labels are of different sizes,(data coming from backend) so I want to adjust the background image according to the length of the label.

For example : Label : "Hi How are you"
In this scenario - the image should fit the label and should look proportionate to the screen

Label : "Hi"
In the scenario - the image should fit the label containing just "Hi", meaning it should shrink based on the label string length.

Is this possible ?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are going for... *"image should fit the label and should look proportionate to the screen"* --- what does that mean? You might want to include a couple images showing the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Take your UIView into a UIScrollView or tableviewcell or collectionviewcell.
2. Give UIView constraint without height.
3. Take your UIImageView and UILabel inside UIView(don't give UILabel height constraint).